# link href attribute display in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

```html
<a href="LINK" data-toggle="tooltip" title="text_">over me</a>
```

How do you display the link of the attribute(href), in tooltip bootstrap?

Comment: The code actually works!!! but in your snippet, you haven't neither included jquery nor bootstrap.js! You include those and it works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Bootstrap Documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) than you could expand the code you just using, but i guess you havent. But here is the code you looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    selector: true,
    title: function() {
      return $(this).attr('href');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="LINK" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Some Text!">Hover over me</a>
```